# MySQL data being lost after getting inserted successfully with Python mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, faker

I'm using `python mysql.connector` for some database operation. My database table structure is like this:

[image]

I running a `python script` with `Faker Package(fake-factory 0.5.0)` to populate this database table. After  insertion I run a query to verify that data is properly stored into the table. The python script shows all inserted data and finishes with `exit code 0`

But when I explore that table through `phpMyadmin` it doesn't show those inserted rows. These inserted data doesn't persist in after the next run yet.

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='001',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='smf')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

for i in range(1, 5):
    query = "insert into user " + "(userid, name) values("+ str(i) + ", '" + fake.name() + "')"
    cursor.execute(query)

query = "select * from user"
cursor.execute(query)

for (x) in cursor:
    print ("name = " + format(x))

cnx.close()
```

Comment: do you need to have a cnx.commit() after the cursor.execute(query) command

Comment: got it. Need a `cnx.commit()`

Comment: When a returned name value contains a single quote, that's going to cause an error in the INSERT query. (Potentially unsafe values included in SQL text must be escaped. Better yet, use prepared statements with bind placeholders.)

Answer (score 6):

By default `Connector/Python` turns `autocommit` off, and MySQL 5.5 and later uses transactional InnoDB tables, so it is necessary to `commit` your changes using the connection's `commit()` method. You could also roll back using the rollback() method.

So, putting `cnx.commit()` command after `cursor.execute(query)` solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `cnx.commit` after calling the first `cursor.execute(query)`. The `commit()` function allows the data to be saved permanently.